# Algorithm for clustering pictures based on date taken

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, grouping

Anyone know of an algorithm that will group pictures into events based on the date the picture was taken.  Obviously I can group by the date, but I'd like something a little more sophisticated that would(might) be able to group pictures spanning multiple days based on the frequency over a certain timespan. Consider the following groupings:

- 1/2/2009 15 photos
- 1/3/2009 20 photos
- 1/4/2009 13 photos
- 1/5/2009 19 photos
- 1/15/2009 5 photos

Potentially these would be grouped into two groups:

1. 1/2/2009 -> 1/5/2009
2. 1/15/2009

Obviously there will be some tolerance(s) that need to be established.

Is there any well established way of doing this, other then inventing my own top/down approach?

Comment: Did you end up with a solution that worked well? If so, would you be able to share your approach? I'm about to work on a similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply pretty much [any standard clustering technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) to this, it's just a matter of defining your distance function correctly.  When you are making your matrix of distances between your photos you should consider a combination of physical distance between locations - if you have it - and temporal distance between their creation timestamps.  [Normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) them and put them on separate dimensions and you may even just be able to take a regular euclidean distance.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just group the pictures that were taken on successive days (no days on which no pictures were taken) together.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to dynamically calculate tolerance based on how many or how big (absolute or %) clusters you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

To get a useful clustering of pictures according to date you require the following:

1) The number of clusters should be variable and not fixed a priori to the clustering

2) The diameter of each cluster should not exceed a specific amount.

The clustering algorithm that best satisfies both requirements is the [QT (quality threshold) clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering#QT_clustering_algorithm).  From Wikipedia:

> QT (quality threshold) clustering
>   (Heyer, Kruglyak, Yooseph, 1999) is an
>   alternative method of partitioning
>   data, invented for gene clustering. It
>   requires more computing power than
>   k-means, but does not require
>   specifying the number of clusters a
>   priori, and always returns the same
>   result when run several times.

Although it is mainly used for gene clustering I think it would fit in very well for what you need.

Comment: Any hierarchical agglomeration technique shares that property.

Comment: Why do you think QT clustering is better?

Comment: hierarchical agglomeration technique will naively merge always the closest two point/cluster pairs at each iteration.  Since you are not considering all clusters for each point you could end up with skewed clusters

Comment: w/ QT wont the first cluster always be the size of the predefined max diameter?

Comment: The first cluster is by definition the cluster having the most points within the given diameter.  Every cluster will have the predefined max diameter if there are enough points.

Comment: Right, which makes it ill suited for this application, unless of course you assume each event is the same duration of time (same diameter).

Comment: @Il-Bhima.  Naive implementations will indeed do that, but it is an easy problem to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to detect the Gaps instead of the Clusters.